# Using php mail() to do simple checks

Tags: email

I am using php mail() (Via piped to program) and my goal is to simply get the email and scan the "from" header to filter it and then if it passes my "rules" or "checks" pass it along to the intended receiver. I have been able to use a sample code to get the mail and I can actually get my "test check" done. The problem I am having is that I cannot get the php mail() function to resend the mail as it was (plain or html). Every time i get my test mail, it comes with all the headers exposed and code. Not a nice and neat email. I also found out that I could encounter problems with this if there are attachments to the mail. I have seen alot of suggestions about going thru PHPMailer and I am willing to entertain that option. I just don't need this to get to complicated. here is the code I am using -

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
$notify= 'myemail@mydomain.com'; // an email address required in case of errors
function mailRead($iKlimit = "") 
    { 
            if ($iKlimit == "") { 
                $iKlimit = 1024; 
            } 
            $sErrorSTDINFail = "Error - failed to read mail from STDIN!"; 
        $fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r"); 

        if (!$fp) { 
            echo $sErrorSTDINFail; 
            exit(); 
        } 
        $sEmail = ""; 
        if ($iKlimit == -1) { 
            while (!feof($fp)) { 
                $sEmail .= fread($fp, 1024); 
            }                     
        } else { 
            while (!feof($fp) && $i_limit < $iKlimit) { 
                $sEmail .= fread($fp, 1024); 
                $i_limit++; 
            }         
        } 
        fclose($fp);
        return $sEmail; 
    }  
$email = mailRead();
$lines = explode("\n", $email);
$to = "";
$from = "";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$splittingheaders = true;
for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($splittingheaders) {
        $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";
        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $subject = $matches[1];
        }
        $tst = substr($subject, -3);
        if ($tst == "win" | $tst == "biz" | $tst == "net"){
        $subject = $subject . "BAD ADDRESS";
        }
        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $from = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $to = $matches[1];
        }
    } else {
        // not a header, but message
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    }

    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
        // empty line, header section has ended
        $splittingheaders = false;
    }
}
mail('noreply@mydomain.com', $subject, $message);
?>
```

I am interested in learning, I am code savvy. Somewhat new to email formatting, but very understanding of PHP. Any help is appreciated. Thanx.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the article. I see that I did not actually "ask" a question so here it is: How do I get the code that uses mail() to resend an email in its original format, so that the end result is a nice and clean email? (I may be thinking of the end result displaying as html)

I am not sure of what part of the code could be affected this is why I posted the entire script. If there is something else that I may have done wrong, can you please point it out directly so that I can comply with the rules. Thank you.

Comment: You posted quite a lot of code. The idea of a **Minimal** example is to reduce it to the smallest piece of code that reproduces your problem, rather than posting whatever code you have.

Comment: Ah, this is why I posted the whole script. I am not sure if either I am not grabbing it right, or if its not being sent right or if I am not formatting it correctly. How would you suggest I proceed? I can post just the "sending" portion of the code, but in the interest of painting "the whole picture" I wanted to include what I thought was pertinent information. Do I just edit the original post and cut out the "retrieval" part of the code? Let me know. I will do what is needed. Thank you.

Comment: I just noticed that there is a ton of comments in the code. I can edit that out and re-post. That will most likely cut it way down.